# Передача класса в пустой список

Tags: python

У меня есть пустой список в который будут добавляться определенные данные. НО, этот пустой список должен принимать в себя ранее созданный класс и работать с его атрибутами (new_list = []). Как должен выглядеть синтаксис, если класс называется, условно, NewClass?

Comment: Список по дефолту может принимать в себя аргументы любых типов, в том числе экземпляры вашего класса, ничего дополнительно писать не нужно

Answer (score 1):

Если тебе нужно именно класс сохранить в список, то [NewClass1, NewClass2, ...] просто и пиши, если экземпляры класса - то [NewClass(), NewClass(), ...]

Добавлять объекты в цикле так:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(1000000):
    my_list.append(NewClass())
```

Comment: В этот пустой список происходит добавление каждый цикл. Таких циклов может быть практически бесконечность. Как в таком случае быть?

Comment: Ответ на комментарий указал в ответе.